# Set a page Item Active or Disable with bootstrap 4 pagination, using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagination, bootstrap-4

I used this code with bootstrap 3, and it worked correctly, when clicking on the page, it appeared as active, but when switching to bootstrap 4, it no longer calls the active class, when I pass the page number inside the "for"

Any ideias how to resolve that?

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item ">
        @{
            if (ViewBag.pageNumber> 1)
            {

                <a class="page-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Barcos", new { search= ViewBag.Search, pageNumber= ViewBag.pageNumber- 1 })">before</a>
            }
            else
            {
                <a class="page-link" href="#">
                    before
                </a>
            }
        }
    </li>
    @{
        var page = ViewBag.pageNumber;
        for (var i = 1; i <= ViewBag.Count; i++)
        {
            <li @(page== i ? "class=page-item active" : "")>
                <a class="page-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Barcos", new {search= ViewBag.Search, pageNumber= i})">@i</a>
            </li>
        }
    }

    <li>

        @if (ViewBag.pageNumber< ViewBag.count)
        {
            <a class="page-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Barcos", new { Search= ViewBag.Search, pageNumber= ViewBag.pageNumber+ 1 })">Next</a>
        }
        else
        {

             <a class="page-link disabled" href="#">
                    Before
                </a>
        }

    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need class="page-item" on all list items, not just for your current page

Corrected bode below.

```
@for (var i = 1; i <= ViewBag.Count; i++)
{

    var page = ViewBag.pageNumber;
    string classes = "page-item";

    if (page == i)
    {
        classes += " active";

    }

    <li class="@classes">
        @Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "Index", "Barcos", new { search = ViewBag.Search, pageNumber = i }, new { @class = "page-link" })
    </li>
}
```

This generates the following HTML

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item ">
        <a class="page-link" href="/Barcos/Index?pageNumber=1">before</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="/Barcos/Index?pageNumber=1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item active">
        <a class="page-link" href="/Barcos/Index?pageNumber=2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="/Barcos/Index?pageNumber=3">3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-link" href="/Barcos/Index?pageNumber=4">Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```